# Area of (concave) deltoid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqmjr.png)

My solution for this is using the cosine theorem to get the side i am missing and then using Heron's formula to find the area of the triangle and then doubling it to get the wanted area. So i have two questions:

1) When i make a $\Delta BDA$ and use the cosine theorem i get the equation $x^2-x*10\sqrt(3)+64=0$ so i get two solutions ($x=5\sqrt(3)-\sqrt(11)$ and $x=5\sqrt(3)+\sqrt(11)$) how would i choose the side?

2) Could someone give me a hint or a solution on how i would solve this problem without cosine theorem? Edit: Perhaps we see that since angle is $60$ we use it to find $AC=10$  and then substract the triangle $\Delta ACD$ which has sides $6,6,10$ ?

Comment: I believe it will be easiest to use your second idea, i.e., calculate and subtract the area of $\Delta ACD$ from $\Delta ABC$.

Comment: Is there any elegant solution ? If it is not too much of a hassle could you confirm that the area of the deltoid is $25\sqrt(3)-5\sqrt(11)$

Comment: @uabimKuP, I got the same answer as you.  Note I dropped a line from $B$ through $D$ to $AC$, with this showing that $\Delta ABC$ is an equilateral triangle.  I then used that to determine the length of $AC$ and the Pythagorean Theorem to get the height of $\Delta ADC$.  Finally, I determined the triangle areas using $\frac{1}{2}$ times the base and height, then subtracting the values.  Depending on how you define "elegant", that is about as good as you'll get.